# Unable to connect to SQL Server Container on Kubernetes on Azure (ACS) from Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I have created a custom SQL Server Database Container Image. I can run that as a container on my local machine (Windows 10 with Docker for Windows). After running that container, I can successfully connect to it from SQL Server Management Studio by using server name as 127.0.0.1:1433.

I am trying to run that same container as a StatefulSet in Kubernetes in Azure.

Below are Kubernetes resources.

Secret (For SQL Server SA password)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: sqlsecret
type: Opaque
data:
  sapassword: base64encodedvalue
```

Storage Class (StatefulSet - External Storage)

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurestorageclass
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
  location: southeastasia
  storageAccount: myaccount
```

External Service (Tried with Headless Service as well, but I need to connect externally from pods also)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sqlservice
  labels:
    name: sqlservice
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
  externalIPs: 
    - Kubernetes-Cluster-LB-Public-IP-Address-From-Azure-Portal
  selector:
    role: sqlservice
```

and finally StatefulSet.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: sqlserverstatefulset
spec:
  serviceName: "sqlservice"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: sqlservice
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: sqlinux
          image: custom-image-from-docker-hub
          env:
            - name: SA_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: sqlsecret
                  key: sapassword
            - name: ACCEPT_EULA
              value: "Y"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          volumeMounts:
            - name: sql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: sql-persistent-storage
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "azurestorageclass"
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Gi
```

I run this command to provision these resources from my local machine (with context pointing to Azure cluster).

```
kubectl create -f c:\sqlkube.yaml
```

All my resources are provisioned successfully. All green, nothing red in Kubernetes dashboard (`kubctl proxy`).

I have also set a Health Probe and Load Balancing Rule for Azure Load Balancer for port 1433.

However, when I enter Public IP address of LB : 1433 as Server Name in SQL Server Management Studio, I get following error.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Service needs to be changed to `type: LoadBalancer`. If you already have provisioned a static IP in same resource group as k8s cluster, you can specify that as `loadBalancerIP: WW.XX.YY.ZZ`. If commented, service will provision a new IP address. Use `kubectl describe service sqlservice` to find out IP address or use k8s dashboard.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sqlservice
  labels:
    app: sqlservice
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  #loadBalancerIP: 52.187.173.125
  ports:
  - port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
  selector:
    app: sqlinux
```